# How to put .min() or .max() as method parameter for a stream?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, max, min

How can I pass the `.min()` or `.max()` expression as a method parameter in a code like this:

Given code:

```
private LocalDate getMaxDate() {
    LocalDate maxdate = dates.stream()
              .max( Comparator.comparing( LocalDate::toEpochDay ) )
              .get();
}

private LocalDate getMinDate() {
    LocalDate maxdate = dates.stream()
              .min( Comparator.comparing( LocalDate::toEpochDay ) )
              .get();
}
```

Code that I expect to have:

```
private LocalDate getDate(SomeType _EXPR_){
        LocalDate maxdate = dates.stream()
                  ._EXPR_( Comparator.comparing( LocalDate::toEpochDay ) )
                  .get();
    }
```

Hint: `_EXPR_` shall be `.min()`, sometimes `.max()`

Comment: Well, you could make `SomeType` an enum (or just a boolean) to switch between min and max, always use `.min()` or `.max()` and just invert the comparator if needed. However, what's the problem with just using the 2 different methods? They'd be more readable and safer to use than passing the "expression" as a parameter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The method is

```
private LocalDate getDate(Function<Comparator<LocalDate>, BinaryOperator<LocalDate>> f) {
  return dates.stream()
              .reduce(f.apply(Comparator.comparing(LocalDate::toEpochDay)))
              .get();
}
```

To call it, use

```
getDate(BinaryOperator::maxBy);
getDate(BinaryOperator::minBy);
```

Beware of `NoSuchElementException` which `Optional#get` may throw.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another option:

```
private LocalDate getMinOrMaxDate (boolean max) {
    Stream<LocalDate> ds = dates.stream();
    Comparator<LocalDate> comp = Comparator.comparing(LocalDate::toEpochDay);
    return (max ? ds.max(comp) : ds.min(comp)).get();
}
```

Comment: This would work better if we're concerned about object count, as this version doesn't create any additional objects. I'd just replace "magic" `true:false` constants with an enum (it's a real shame Java doesn't have one already).

Comment: @M.Prokhorov if there was an enum, what constants would it be made of? `MIN`, `MAX`? What would these constants mean in a broader, contextless sense?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass in a `boolean` as such, and call `Comparator#reversed()` as required:

```
private LocalDate getDate(boolean max) {
    Comparator<LocalDate> comparator = Comparator.comparing(LocalDate::toEpochDay);
    if (!max) comparator = comparator.reversed();
    return dates.stream().max(comparator).get();
}
```

It is also possible to implement the same behaviour using an `enum` instead of a `boolean` as the parameter. This is probably better for readability.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to pass the .min() resp. .max() methods from the Stream class. This could be done like:

```
   private LocalDate getDate(BiFunction<Stream, Comparator<? super LocalDate>, Optional<LocalDate>> _EXPR_){
       return _EXPR_.apply(dates.stream(), Comparator.comparing(LocalDate::toEpochDay)).get();
   }
```

Which then can be called with

```
getDate(Stream::min);
getDate(Stream::max);
```

This approach is rather unsafe, not very elegant and adds more complexity than having the getMin() and getMax() method. It might be worth considering to keep both methods for the sake of readability.

If you really want to avoid the duplicate code and/or generify the method I'd probably go with something like the solution cameron1024 has suggested.

Comment: how would you call this method?